# Cannot trigger click on class when selector change

Tags: select, triggers, click

I really appreciate if i got help this problem. I lost almost a week to find but i can't solve this

I knew i am not allowed to post link but if can please make it nofollow.
http://giayattom.com/san-pham/giay-sandal-da-ca-sau-cao-cap-at15-01

My target is when i click on number 1 on images also link to 1 on tab select (1 -- 1 ; 2--2; 3--3) (I did it thanks to this

```
$('ul.tabs-content a').click(function() {
  var node = $(this).closest('#content');
  var this_value = $(this).attr('title');
  node.find('#pa_color').val(this_value).trigger('change');
  return false;
})
```

But when i click on tab select it wont trigger click on images as i expect. Please help me solve this problem. Many thanks.

I used this

```
$("#pa_color").change(function () {
  var this_class = $(this).val();
  console.log(this_class);
  $('ul.tabs-content a.'+this_class).trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  `$('ul.tabs-content a.'+this_class).trigger('click');`

to  `$('ul.tabs-content a.'+this_class)[0].click();`

Comment: Very thank I solved my problem.. But i got another problem when i check console.log i saw that looped 2 times. This cause Add to Cart button can't get the Variant ID of that product.